# Redirecting with 401 MEAN stack res.redirect

Tags: angular, typescript, express, routes

I am trying to make a MEAN app with redirection to a login page when you try and access the page without having logged in. I am using a MEAN stack, and am trying to display an Angular page that would log in.

My express routing looks like this:

```
app.use('/app/', helpers.checkLogin);

// Angular app
app.use('/app/', express.static('lib/dist'));
app.use('/app/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html'));
});
```

And there is angular routing set up like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }...]
```

And the helpers.checkLogin function looks like this:

```
export function checkLogin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)
{
    if (req.originalUrl === '/app/login') {
        next();
    } else {
        if (checkIfLoggedIn()) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/app/login');
        }
    }
}
```

My main problem is that it will continually redirect. Also, it would be better for me to send a status code of 401 with the redirection, but res.redirect doesn't allow 400 codes.

Thanks

Edit 1: For clarity, I do not know how to redirect with a 401 status code, and I don't understand how to set up my routing so that I will still use the angular component for logging in, but not redirect when I try to access this and am not already logged in.

Comment: Welcome to stack! In order to have a good chance at getting an answer, its important to ask a clear and specific question. This isn't a place for asking advice or getting someone else to debug your code (there is a code review section for that). Please try to reform your question to be specific about the issue you are experiencing, for example, what exactly do you mean it will continually redirect?

Comment: @JonChurch with the code above, when you run it, in the network tab on the dev tools for chrome, it shows multiple requests to /login. Additionally, there are errors that say `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in login:1`. This is in the html for the angular component Login.

Comment: Are you using some kind of template? Or what does your login mechanism looks like in the angular app?